# Converting Every Other Char to Upper Case i.e. abcd --> aBcD

Tags: java, string, uppercase

So I'm just starting to learn Java this afternoon. What would be the best way of doing this? And what have I done wrong? At the moment, I just get no output :(

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class ClassA {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner MyScan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Word: ");
        String UI = MyScan.nextLine();
        UI.toLowerCase();
        String s;
        String word = "";
        for (int i = 0; i <= UI.length()-1; i++) {
            s = UI.substring(i, i+1);
            if (i % 2 == 1) {
                s.toUpperCase();    
            }
            word.concat(s);
        }
        System.out.print(word);
        MyScan.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`String`s in java are immutable. This means that whatever modifying operations you call on a `String`, you need to assign its result to the original value in order to actually modify it.

So in your case you should type `word = word.concat(s)` instead of simply `word.concat(s)`. `word.concat(s)` creates a new instance and unless you assign it to `word`, its value will remain intact.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the values of the case conversions and the concatenation to create a new instance of the string as strings are immutable in java. change the following lines as shown.

```
UI = UI.toLowerCase();
s = s.toUpperCase();
word = word.concat(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate implementation -- it uses StringBuffer for concatenation, and deals with each character as a character instead of a String
`

```
public static String everyOtherLowerCase(String input) {    
    input = input.toLowerCase();

    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer("");

    for(int x=0; x<input.length(); x++) {
        Character c = input.charAt(x);

        if(x % 2 == 0) result.append(c);
        else result.append(Character.toUpperCase(c));
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

`

As others have pointed out, Strings are immutable; it's best for performance reasons to append to a StringBuffer rather than constantly re-creating and re-allocating String objects.  This is a pretty common performance mis-step in java.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct, but I'm going to have a stab at making it clearer.

Strings are *immutable* meaning that you cannot change them. But you *can* make a new String and assign it to the same variable. None of the methods of `String` change the content. Many of them return a new `String`. So:

```
String s = "Hello";
s.replace("H","J");
```

... creates a new `String` of "Jello", *then throws it away*.

```
String s1 = "Hello";
String s2 = s.replace("H","J");
```

... creates a new `String` of "Jello", and assigns it to `s2`.

```
String s1 = "Hello";
s1 = s1.replace("H","J");
```

... creates a new `String` of "Jello", assigns it to `s1`, throwing away the old `String` ("Hello") previously assigned to `s1`.

The class `StringBuilder` exists for the occasions when you *do* want to modify a sequence of characters in-place.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Hello");
sb.replace(0,1,"J");
```

... makes `sb` contain "Jello" instead of "Hello".

This knowledge should give you what you need to fix your program.